# Extract a string within a string

Tags: java

How can I access `WWW.GOOGLE.COM` within this `String`.

I can use the `substring` method to chop off `javascript:linkToExternalSite('` but how can I remove the subsequest string.

So that

```
javascript:linkToExternalSite('WWW.GOOGLE.COM','D','SDFSDX2131D','R','','X','D','DFA','SAFD')
```

becomes

```
WWW.GOOGLE.COM
```

This works

```
string = string.substring(31, string.length());
string = string.substring(0, string.indexOf("'"));
```

Comment: The format of linkToExternalSite is always same or it may be change the format.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=url+regex - hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `myString = "www.google.com','..."`

You could do:

```
result = myString.substring(0, myString.indexof("'");
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to, there is an easier way:

```
final String it = "WWW.GOOGLE.COM";
```

No need for chop, cut or other bloody operations.

Comment: How is this supposed to work, are you not extracting this string by just looking at it yourself ?

Comment: *You* said you want to extract that from the more complex string above - yet what I've shown is there is an easier way to get the string "WWW.GOOGLE.COM"

Answer (score 2):

Use regex

```
String substring = //YOURSUBSTRING
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[W]{3}[.A-Z]+[.COM|.CO.UK]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

    Matcher matcher = p.matcher(substring);

        if (matcher.find()){
            String Url = matcher.group();
            System.out.println(matcher.group());

        }
```

Comment: btw the regex is pretty basic and could be improved !

Answer (score 0):

You Can use the substring() Method Of String Class!